# How to create multiple lists?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create multiple lists like the following:

```
l1 = []  
l2 = []  
..  
ln = []
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary instead, or use a nested list? Whenever you are thinking: *I need to generate variable names*, **stop**. You want a dictionary instead, with your 'variable names' keys in that dictionary. If the names are sequential (numbered starting at 0 or 1), use a list instead.

Comment: It is always better to tell what do you really want to implement -- I mean the *bigger picture*. The solution may be different than you think.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you can do is use a dictionary:

```
>>> obj = {}
>>> for i in range(1, 21):
...     obj['l'+str(i)] = []
... 
>>> obj
{'l18': [], 'l19': [], 'l20': [], 'l14': [], 'l15': [], 'l16': [], 'l17': [], 'l10': [], 'l11': [], 'l12': [], 'l13': [], 'l6': [], 'l7': [], 'l4': [], 'l5': [], 'l2': [], 'l3': [], 'l1': [], 'l8': [], 'l9': []}
>>>
```

You can also create a list of lists using list comprehension:

```
>>> obj = [[] for i in range(20)]
>>> obj
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>>
```

Comment: You could do `[[]]*20` instead of using the `range` function.

Comment: `[[]] * 20` gives you a list of  20 references for the inner `[ ]` instead, this is incorrect. Try appending 1 value into the list, all of them will have that values too. Indeed if `L = [[]]*20` then `L[0] is L[1]` will be `True`

Answer (score 3):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
obj = {i:[] for i in list(range(1,5))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of lists:

```
lists = []
n = 20
for i in range(n):
    lists.append([])

print lists[0] # Prints []
print lists[19] # Prints []
```

Comment: or `lists = [[] for _ in range(n)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just Extending Already Accepted Answer,
Using Enumerate to initiate default values in list.
Accessing list and adding values which was not mentioned.

```
range_list = list(range (int(input())))
obj = {}


for i, j in enumerate(range_list): # assigning default values
    obj['l'+str(i)] = [j**2]
   
print(obj['l0'])
print(type(obj['l0']))

obj['l0'] = list(range(5)) # accessing list
print(obj['l0'])

#3 asking user, how many list to be created 
#[0] default value in first list
#<class 'list'>
#[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] current value in first list

#[Program finished]
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about your answer. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: what part were you not able to understand? I am just extending already accepted answer and have made lots of comments.

Comment: Try adding a line towards how your answer is different. See other posts in this thread to get an idea of what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a for loop to create n lists.

`for i in range(10):
  a_i = [i] #Stores the corresponding value of i in each a_i list.
  print(a_i)`

The variable a_i changes as i increments, so it becomes a_1, a_2, a_3 ... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to do that if you want to create variables. but instead, u should use a dictionary as mentioned above. but anyway I am going to show you how to create variables as you asked.

```
for i in range(num_vars):
     globals()[f'ls{i}'] = []

print(ls1) # lsn should work
```